# How can I determine if a peak in a spectrofluorometer's spectrum is erroneous?

Tags: spectroscopy, harmonics, fluorescence

Let me give you the specific scenario since I'm really not sure which factors are relevant or not:

Our lab made our own upconversion nanoparticles (UCNP) following a popular paper on the subject.  Briefly on UCNP: instead of taking in higher energy photons and converting them to lower energy photons like fluorescent materials usually do, UCNP take two or more lower energy photons and spit out one higher energy photon, hence "upconversion".  I mention this because my question is about the spectrofluorometer instrument itself, so anyone with expertise will hopefully be able to help me even if they are not familiar with UCNP.  For fluorometry concerns, the crystal lattice was composed of the popular NaYF$_4$ crystal and was doped with Tm, Yb, and Nd

We believe that the particles we produced work to some extent as their XRD, EDACS, and TEM all read as very similar to the crystals described in the paper.  To be specific, our particles were made to take 980 nm or 808 nm intense laser light and emit somewhere in the UV spectrum with the strongest peak at 347 nm, although smaller UV and visible light peaks will also appear.

However, my adviser looked at the spectrofluorometry results and was disappointed.  While their *were* peaks in the UV range, there appeared to be *no* peaks at 347 nm.  My adviser believes that the UV peaks that are there are actually harmonics, just artifacts produced by the spectrofluorometer, rather than true peaks.

So, my question: how would such "harmonics" appear?  What is the mechanism of action?  Most importantly, is there a way to determine if a signal is a harmonic as opposed to one that is actually produced by our manufactured UCNP?

The reason why this is so concerning is that the experiment we used the UCNP in worked!  The results were small, but definitely there.  However, the only mechanism that makes sense to me is that UV is being produced.  If this turns out not to be true, then what other mechanism could be working?  Could the crystals simply be heating up somehow?

Anyway, I desperately need an answer as this paper will finish off my thesis and I can be free of graduate school finally.  Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you could post the spectra here. You're talking about peaks without telling us what peaks, how strong they are, how they are shaped and a myriad other things that can all be exhibited in a single image.

Comment: Can't you put in something that definately doesn't upconvert and see if you still get the peaks?